# Can not catch exception, while vscode dart-code DOES catch the exception

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I have a line of code in my Flutter app that results in VSCode breaking on an exception.

To have this behaviour occur, I enabled 'break on uncaught exceptions' in the vscode dart-code extension.

Observe the following code. The line with the await on it makes vscode break on an 'uncaught exception', BUT the exception is certainly being caught by me.

How is vscode breaking on an uncaught exception on this line without the exception actually being subsequently caught by the runZoned or try/catch?

```
runZoned(
  () async {
    try {
      if (_readCharSubscription != null)
        await _readCharSubscription.cancel();
    }
    catch(e) {
      print("caught");
    }
  },
  onError: (e) {
    print("caught");
  }
);
```

Comment: You should raise an issue here: https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the exception is not really uncaught. There were some cases where the VM would pause on exceptions that will be handled, even when the settings are set to only break on uncaught exceptions.

The relevant SDK issue is here:

https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/37953